# How do you move an answer to a comment when the author of said answer isn't the OP, but wants to comment on another answer?

Tags: discussion

How would I move (or tell a mod to move) an answer to a comment on another user's post when they don't have enough rep to comment?

Example (this was an answer):

> JamesTheAwesomeDude, your instructions are good except for some little things. In order to get to your downloads you can't just type
>   *cd Downloads* its *cd /home/user/*/Downloads* without * *. Once in that directory, all you have to do it type 
>       NAMES
>       The 1st USB drive plugged into an x86 Chromebook will be /dev/sdb
>       The 1st SD Card plugged into an x86 Chromebook will be /dev/mmcblk0
>       The 1st USB drive plugged into an ARM Chromebook will be /dev/sda
>       The 1st SD Card plugged into an ARM Chromebook will be /dev/mmcblk1
>
> ```
> sudo dd if=put your os name here.iso of=dev/name of your usb bs=4
>
> for example, (for windows_xp_pro.iso)
>
> sudo dd if=windows_xp_pro.iso of=dev/sda bs=4
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Flags!

We use flags for just about everything on these sites. If you see *anything* wrong, just flag it and a moderator or experienced user will take a look.

In this case you can just use a basic "Not an answer" flag, or use a custom flag and explain that the answer should be converted to a comment.